# NameError wile add config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, nameerror, authenticity-token, remote-forms

I was working on ajax on my rails app and I got a ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error.

and I read this

> config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms allows you
>   to set the default behavior for authenticity_token in forms with
>   remote: true. By default it's set to false, which means that remote
>   forms will not include authenticity_token, which is helpful when
>   you're fragment-caching the form. Remote forms get the authenticity
>   from the meta tag, so embedding is unnecessary unless you support
>   browsers without JavaScript. In such case you can either pass
>   authenticity_token: true as a form option or set this config setting
>   to true.

from [RailsGuides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

so  I add `config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms=true` to \config\application.rb

and restart rails server ,then an error happened

*/Users/haha/railsbridge/railsfun/ruby12weeks/eat/config/application.rb:5:in': undefined local variable or method config' for main:Object (NameError)*

Did I put it to wrong place?

this is [my github](https://github.com/qjpioneer/Foodie)

Answer (score 0):

That line or any config line should be inside `Application class`, that is after line `12` and before line `16` in your github code

Comment: Happens with everyone. If it solves your problem, dont mind to upvote and mark as answer